# How to extend Liferay CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, liferay

I am using liferay 6.0.ee sp2 version.
I want to remove and extend Liferay CKEditor. As I have created hook and tried to modified this jsp

> "/html/js/editor/ckeditor/ckconfig.jsp"

I have defined below properties in jsp.

```
CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
CKEDITOR.config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'Underline';
```

Changes are not reflected on CKEditor. What could be the issue. Any pointers.

Comment: Is your hook overriding the JSP properly located in tomcat?

Comment: Yes, It is properly located in tomcat.

Comment: There will be two JSP, one starting with portal_ckconfig.jsp and ckconfig.jsp. Is that what you are observing in your case too?

Comment: In my case, Also two files are generated ckconfig.portal.jsp and ckconfig.jsp in Tomcat.

Comment: And ckconfig.jsp is containing the changes you want?

Comment: Yes, Custom changes are in ckconfig.jsp

Comment: Ok, it means that fine there with Hook. Are you observing any JS error(s) in console?

Comment: No, Not getting any js error in console.

Comment: Can you share your hook code?

Comment: My "test-hook" override only one jsp of liferay portal source's ckconfig.jsp and I have additionally added only three lines inside the jsp. or give me your email address so I can send it to you.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Hooks. I have been working on the ext environment. Though, you can send me at parkash-kumar@hotmail.com

Comment: Did you check my hook?

Comment: I have received your email, will let you know, if I find any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am awaited.

Comment: It would nice if you can elaborate as to what you intend to do with the properties and are these new properties or is given by ck-editor?

Comment: These are predefined properties by CKEditor. Problem is occurred in CKEditor source which is whenever clicked  source tab it will automatically added this "<p> &nbsp; </p>" inside it. I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any issue with your Hook, it is doing its job properly by overriding the CKEditor config JSP.

I have noticed that some of the configuration changes are functional as desired, e.g.

```
CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'stylescombo,font';
CKEDITOR.config.height = 500;
```

However, the following one is not working:

```
CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'Underline';
```

There seems to be some naming convention issue for the plugins name. Like we used `stylescombo` for `Styles` and `font` for `FontSize`, that removed plugins from the toolbar.

Now, there are two possibilities left for removing `Underline` plugin:
1. Either remove it from the toolbar that you are using.
2. Or create separate toolbar excluding the plugins you desire to remove.